# Disable the autoadding of rows in the DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'd like my users to not be able to add-or even autoadd- rows to the datagridview.

What setting do I need to set for this?

Edit: I also need to lock a particular column from editing. A user cannot enter/modify text in column[0] of the datagridview.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In DataGridView properties set AllowUserToAddRow to false.
And for a column you want to lock, set it's property to ReadOnly.

Comment: Yes, and there's even a Checkbox for it in the DataGrid smart-thingy.

Comment: What property should I set to ReadOnly? Since I'm adding the columns at runtime, can I access that by code?